# Ubuntu 8.04 unresponsive after restart

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, fsck, ubuntu-8.04

I have a Godaddy Dedicated server running Ubuntu 8.04.  When I restart the server it will randomly not come back online.  I cannot access it through SSH or the web.

Godaddy support has to reboot the server and disable iptables, restart SSH and then run `fsck` on the hard drive.

This has happened multiple times, I'm trying to find where the issue is coming from.

I setup iptables > 1 year ago and cannot remember how I set it up and cannot tell if my iptables are to blame or not.

My iptables -L is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 798K packets, 65M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   61  6040 fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 797K packets, 47M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   61  6040 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Hard Drive was in the process of dying and in the span of 1.5 days I had to run `fsck` to fix the corruption 5 times.